# Google Maps API updating a marker from a different script

Tags: javascript, html, api, google-maps

Hi i have the following code. I have initiated my google maps inside a script as the documentation states. I want to update the marker from a different script in the code. How would i do this? When the marker updates will it be live or will the page have to be refreshed? If the page has to be refreshed how can i do it some it update live?

```
<!--The div element for the map -->
         <div id="map">
          <% var getLat = lat %>
          <% var getlong = long %> 
         <script>
            // Initialize and add the map
            function initMap() {
             // The location of city  
              var passLat = <%= getLat  %>;
              var passLong = <%= getlong  %>;
              var city = {lat: passLat, lng: passLong}; 

              // The map, centered at city 
              var map = new google.maps.Map(
              document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 10, center: city});
              // The marker, positioned at Uluru
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: city, map: map});

             }                            
         </script>
            <script 
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYAPI&callback=initMap" defer>
          </script>
      </div>
      <h3 id = "LocalPhotos"> What the Local Area Looks Like:</h3>
      <div id = "flick">
          <script>
              var city2 = {lat: 27, lng: 152}; 
              marker.position(city2);
              //update the marker here. But this code doesn't work

              </script>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have three issues:

1. currently your `marker` variable is local to the `initMap` function.  Move it to the global scope:

```
// in global scope, outside the function
var marker;
function initMap() {
  // The location of city  
  var passLat = <%= getLat  %>;
  var passLong = <%= getlong  %>;
  var city = {lat: passLat, lng: passLong}; 

  // The map, centered at city 
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), 
    {zoom: 10, center: city});
  // The marker, positioned at Uluru
  // initialize the global variable (remove the "var")
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: city, map: map});
}
```

2. the `marker` doesn't have a documented `position` member, use the documented [`setPosition`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Marker.setPosition) method:

```
var city2 = {
  lat: 27,
  lng: 152
};
marker.setPosition(city2);
```

3. The other issue is that the code that sets the marker position runs before the API loads and the code that creates the map runs.  That can be fixed wit `setTimeout` like this (but that problem should be solved in the context of your application, setTimeout is a bandaid over the real issue):

```
var city2 = {
  lat: 27,
  lng: 152
};
setTimeout(function() {
marker.setPosition(city2);
map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
//update the marker here. But this code doesn't work
}, 5000)
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/p3dq7zc0/1/)

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<!--The div element for the map -->
<div id="map">
  <script>
    var marker, map;
    // Initialize and add the map
    function initMap() {
      // The location of city  
      var passLat = 37.4419;
      var passLong = -122.1419;
      var city = {
        lat: passLat,
        lng: passLong
      };

      // The map, centered at city 
      map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: city
        });
      // The marker, positioned at Uluru
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: city,
        map: map
      });

    }
  </script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" defer>
  </script>
</div>
<h3 id="LocalPhotos"> What the Local Area Looks Like:</h3>
<div id="flick">
  <script>
    // the middle of the pacific ocean?
    var city2 = {
      lat: 27,
      lng: 152
    };
    setTimeout(function() {
      marker.setPosition(city2);
      map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
      //update the marker here. But this code doesn't work
    }, 5000)
  </script>
</div>
```